# Using Google site verification meta tag on Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need Google site verification for my site. Google gives me a meta tag to add on my site's head tag.

Does Magento provide any configuration interface for that OR do I need to modify a file?

Answer (score 6):

- Log in to your **Admin** account
- Navigate to ***System*** > **Configuration** > Under "**General**" section on left side > **Design** and under "**HTML Head**" paste the code in the input filed next to "**Miscellaneous** **Scripts**"

This is where to place the verification code for **Google** (Youtube, Webmaster, Adsense), e.g.

```
<-meta name="google-site-verification" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /->
```

Comment: Ask new questions through Ask Question tag.

Answer (score 4):

Add this piece of xml in one of your layout files:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="google_verification" as="google_verification">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[CODE FROM GOOGLE HERE]]></text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Clear the cache and refresh.

Comment: Hi thank you for response. I see you respond very quickly. I found one option System->General->Design->HTML Head->Miscellaneous Scripts

I can put the the meta tag provided by google. Do you think you answer better? Can I get any benefits in speed issue?

Comment: I don't think my answer has any benefits. I'm a developer and I usually like to control thinkg through files. If I tell the non-technical client "Fill in that in the backend" I might spend some time later fixing what he breaks. That's the only reason. If this is not the case for you, you can safely use the config setting. I guess it slipped my mind because I don't use it. But it's a valid way t do it.

Answer (score 1):

**For Magento 2.1 & 2.2:**

1-> Go to your admin panel.

2-> Go to `CONTENT > Configuration`.

3-> Press `edit` for your current theme or global theme.

4-> Open the section `HTML Head`.

5-> Paste in the `Scripts and Style Sheets` section the meta tag code.

6-> Press the `Save Configuration` button in the top right corner (see image below).

[image]